# How to do method overloading for null argument?

Tags: java, oop, null, overloading

I have added three methods with parameters:

```
public static  void doSomething(Object obj) {
    System.out.println("Object called");
}

public static  void doSomething(char[] obj) {
    System.out.println("Array called");
}

public static  void doSomething(Integer obj) {
    System.out.println("Integer called");
}
```

When I am calling `doSomething(null)` , then compiler throws error as **ambiguous methods**. So is the issue because `Integer` and `char[]` methods or `Integer` and `Object` methods?

Comment: Just change the `Integer` to `int`.

Comment: @Mudassir: and what exactly would that solve?

Comment: @Joachim Sauer: If changed from Integer to int, then null isn't referred to primitive types in Java, so the compiler will not throw error.

Comment: @Joachim Sauer: It'll not throw the `reference to doSomething is ambiguous` error.

Answer (score 254, accepted):

Java will always try to use the most specific applicable version of a method that's available (see [JLS §15.12.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2.5)).

`Object`, `char[]` and `Integer` can all take `null` as a valid value. Therefore all 3 version are applicable, so Java will have to find the most specific one.

Since `Object` is the super-type of `char[]`, the array version is more specific than the `Object`-version. So if only those two methods exist, the `char[]` version will be chosen.

When both the `char[]` and `Integer` versions are available, then **both** of them are more specific than `Object` but none is more specific than the other, so Java can't decide which one to call. In this case you'll have to explicitly mention which one you want to call by casting the argument to the appropriate type.

Note that in practice this problem occurs far more seldom than one might think. The reason for this is that it only happens when you're explicitly calling a method with `null` or with a variable of a rather un-specific type (such as `Object`).

On the contrary, the following invocation would be perfectly unambiguous:

```
char[] x = null;
doSomething(x);
```

Although you're still passing the value `null`, Java knows exactly which method to call, since it will take the type of the variable into account.

Comment: This is stated for Java 7. Does that also apply to previous Java versions? I mean: If you have several method signatures with parameters only along a type hierarchy, than you are on the save side with null as actual value? And if you have built a "hierarchy for" like in the example here, then you are not?

Comment: I'm pretty sure those rules are the same for at least everything since Java 1.1 (except for the addition of generics, obviously).

Comment: Does this mean that if compiler were to choose in between doSomething(String str) and doSomething(Object obj) during runtime with doSomething(null), doSomething(String str) will be called.

Answer (score 56):

Each pair of these three methods is ambiguous by itself when called with a `null` argument. Because each parameter type is a reference type.

The following are the three ways to call one specific method of yours with null.

```
doSomething( (Object) null);
doSomething( (Integer) null);
doSomething( (char[]) null);
```

May I suggest to remove this ambiguity if you actually plan to call these methods with `null` arguments. Such a design invites errors in the future.

Comment: Only `Integer`-`char[]` pair is ambiguous, because in other two cases, Java compiler can choose most specific choice, like @JoachimSauer described.

Comment: @kajacx: OPs original question was about calling these methods with `null` as parameter. Under that precondition, all three pairs are ambiguous. For the general case, I agree that only `Integer - char[]` pair is ambiguous.

Comment: what about `doSomething(null)` for 
`public static  void doSomething(String str) {
   System.out.println("String called");
}`

This will return string called.

Comment: Is it possible to use an anotation like "nullable" or "not nullable" and set up the declarations so only the one method you want to get a null with so that an explicit "null" (yet implicit null type) argument always unambiguously selects a specific overload ??

Answer (score 8):

`null` is a valid value for any of the three types; so the compiler cannot decide which function to use. Use something like `doSomething((Object)null)` or `doSomething((Integer)null)` instead.

Comment: I removed the method with Integer parameter, it's invoking the function and returning output as **"Array Called"**, so what's the contract between **Array and Object**?

Comment: Java arrays are also Objects.

Answer (score 2):

Every class in Java extends Object class.Even Integer class also extends Object. Hence both Object and Integer are considered as Object instance. So when you pass null as a parameter than compiler gets confused that which object method to call i.e. With parameter Object or parameter Integer since they both are object and their reference can be null. But the primitives in java does not extends Object.

Answer (score 1):

I Have tried this and when there is exactly one pair of overloaded method and one of them has a parameter type Object then the compiler will always select the method with more specific type.  But when there is more than one specific type, then the compiler throws an ambiguous method error.

Since this is a compile time event, this can only happen when one intentionally passes null to this method.  If this is done intentionally then it is better to overload this method again with no parameter or create another method altogether.

Answer (score 0):

there is an ambiguity because of `doSomething(char[] obj)` and `doSomething(Integer obj)`.

char[] and Integer both are the same superior for null that's why they are ambiguous.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Sample{
  public static void main (String[] args) {
       Sample s = new Sample();
       s.printVal(null);

    } 
    public static void printVal(Object i){
        System.out.println("obj called "+i);
    }

    public static void printVal(Integer i){
        System.out.println("Int called "+i);
    }
}
```

The output is Int called null and so ambiguity is with char[] and Integer

Comment: Do you have idea why this method will called ```public static void printVal(Object i){
        System.out.println("obj called "+i);
    } ```