# automatic upcast when you call function with null

Tags: java, upcasting

This code prints out `MyUrgentException`. Could anybody explain why?

```
class MyException extends Exception{
}

class MyCriticalException extends MyException{
}

class MyUrgentException extends MyCriticalException{
}

public class Test{
  public void handler(MyException ex){
    System.out.println("MyException");
  }

  public void handler(MyCriticalException ex){
    System.out.println("MyCriticalException");
  }

  public void handler(MyUrgentException ex){
    System.out.println("MyUrgentException");
  }

  public static void main(String [] args){
    new Test().handler(null);
  }
}
```

Comment: Here, the code doesn't compile because the compiler can't determine which handler to bind. How did you compile this code?

Comment: It compiles for me in java 1.6

Comment: @Aaron: Compiles for me without warnings. The problem would occur if there where overloaded handlers of different object types (and not just a supertype and two subtypes).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5229809/method-overloading-for-null-parameter/5229890#5229890) for a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5229809/method-overloading-for-null-parameter).

See [JLS 15.12.2](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/expressions.doc.html#289905):

> [...] There may be more than one such method declaration, in which case the most specific one is chosen.

So to answer your question. When several overloaded methods are applicable for a specific type, the most specific, or "upcast" if you want, methods is called.

From a intuitive perspective this also makes sense. When you declare:

```
public void handler(MyException ex) {...}
```

You are saying: "I know how to handle a general `MyException`".

And when you are declaring:

```
public void handler(MyUrgentException ex){...}
```

You are saying: "I know how to handle the specific case of a `MyUrgentException`", and therefore also the general case of a `MyException`.