# Method overload selection with null

Tags: java, overloading

Given this code:

```
class Overloading
extends Object
{

static public void target(Object val, String chk) { System.out.println("Object["+val+"] :: Should be "+chk); }
static public void target(String val, String chk) { System.out.println("String["+val+"] :: Should be "+chk); }

static public void main(String[] args) {
    Object                              obj=null;

    target(null        ,"Object");
    target((Object)null,"Object");
    target(obj         ,"Object");
    }
}
```

the output is (unexpectedly) as follows:

```
String[null] :: Should be Object
Object[null] :: Should be Object
Object[null] :: Should be Object
```

The problem is with the first line, which I expect to be the same as the other two.  Furthermore, I would swear that until recently the compiler would give me an ambiguous invocation warning for the plain `null` call.  However compiling and testing with Java 5 and 6 yields the same results.

This is a significant issue for me since I have a lot of code which uses this pattern of using an overloaded "default" parameter of different types to select a return type and infer required conversion/parsing.  Can anyone explain what is going on here?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Method Overloading for NULL parameter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5229809/method-overloading-for-null-parameter)

Comment: It's related, but not a dupe.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Java has always worked the same way: the "most specific" applicable overload is always chosen. Since `String` is a subclass of `Object`, it is "more specific", and the `String` overload is chosen. If the overloads were for, say `String` and `Integer`, and you tried to pass `null`, then you would indeed get a compile-time ambiguity error, since they are both at the same level of the same inheritance hierarchy.

Comment: Yes, I believe you are correct; in other code I also had a overrides for either Number or primitive arrays, both of which are sufficient to trigger an ambiguity warning.  I have resolved my current problem by adding a Number overload to conflict with String... but now I am much less happy with this general pattern (although there's now too much code depending on it to be worth changing it all).

Comment: @SoftwareMonkey, i m facing similar problem as you did. i solved by adding a line in the function: `static public void target(String val, String chk) { if (val == null) { target((Object) val, chk); } System.out.println("String["+val+"] :: Should be "+chk); }`. Do you think it works well?

Comment: @midnite: No, that doesn't do it.  In my case I use the parameter type to select the function invoked, which in turn determines the *return* type.  But the `null` case is special and I need the ambiguity warning to remind the programmer to supply a "typed" null (that is, a specifically typed value initialized to null instead of the keyword `null`) to select the intended return type.

Comment: Firstly, my apology that my code above was buggy. It should be `if (val == null) { target((Object) val, chk); return; }`. And thanks @SoftwareMonkey. This is really worth-thinking in the design. My case is a bit different. i am using the same function name for functions of different purposes. One `x(String, Object)` which i want to match everything except Strings. Another `x(String, String)` is doing a different thing. i know using both `x` might be bad. But it makes the user codes shorter and simpler (and seem smarter). Any recommendation with this?

Comment: How conflicts are resolved for functions having primitive data type, For ex. func(int, long) and func (long,int) and called as func(4,4).

Comment: @hermant: the literal value `4` is an `int` unless specifically cast like `(long)4`.

Answer (score 3):

***Remember that the literal `null` is of type "special null type", not of type `Object`***

A common confusion is that the literal `null` is of type `Object`, thus leading people to believe the closest matched signature is `target(Object val, String chk)`.

The literal `null` is actually of type "[special null type]" ([Java Language Spec (JLS) 4](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/typesValues.html)).  If it were possibly to define such a method, the closest match would be `target([special null type] val, String chk)`.

However, since there isn't such a method (you couldn't create one), the compiler looks for the closest match through subtyping ([JLS 15.12.2.2](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#15.12.2.2)).  The direct supertype of the [special null type] are all reference types ([JLS 4.10.2](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/typesValues.html#4.10.2)) (e.g. String) and Object is a supertype of String.

---

Perhaps a more intuitive way to look at it is via the JLS's intuitive definition for the "most specific method" ([JLS 15.12.2.5](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#15.12.2.5)):

> "The informal intuition is that one method is more specific than
>   another if any invocation handled by the first method could be passed
>   on to the other one without a compile-time type error."

Of the two methods that the call `target(null ,"Object")` matches, any call to

```
void target(String val, String chk)
```

could be handled by

```
void target(Object val, String chk)
```

so intuitively `void target(String val, String chk)` is the "most specific" that could be called without a type error.

See the [JLS 15.12.2.5](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#15.12.2.5) for how the "most specific" is formally defined.