# Overloaded constructor with different object arguments

Tags: java, oop, constructor

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Method Overloading for NULL parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5229809/method-overloading-for-null-parameter)

Quick question about "best practices" when coding in Java. I have a class that can be constructed with two different types of objects (a HashMap or a separate class that I call a SearchTerm). I usually have pretty good handlers in the case where the client gives a null argument through the constructor, but if this does happen, the VM collapses and says the argument was ambiguous. (It makes sense, since the null argument could have been referring to either object.)

How are these situations usually dealt with? Is it bad form to allow separate objects as arguments?

Comment: That's a compiler error.  What's the problem?

Comment: The VM should handle which constructor to call based on the argument type.

Comment: @WilliamVanRensselaer - but it doesn't.  Sal, can you use a factory to construct these objects, and have the factory reject the case where the argument is null?  Or if the null case is valid, have a third constructor with one argument fewer that the factory uses.

Comment: This has already been dealt with before:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5229809/method-overloading-for-null-parameter

Comment: @DavidWallace - That's what I was looking for! I wanted a good strategy to deal with this situation, and a factory seems to take care of it. Thanks for the link Sid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless I'm misunderstanding something, this ambiguity error should only occur if you try to call the constructor with `null` as the argument. If you want to work around this, you can cast the argument to the class you want to use, like so:

```
new YourClass((SearchTerm) null);
```

That way the compiler knows that even though the argument is `null`, it's supposed to treat it like a `null` instance of `SearchTerm`.

If you have an instance of `SearchTerm` that happens to be null, there shouldn't be a problem:

```
SearchTerm searchTerm = null;
new YourClass(searchTerm);
```

should work without ambiguity errors because the compiler knows the what type the instance is, even though it's null.