# How to choose between two method of the same name in Java

Tags: java, overloading

I'm trying to access a method in a class I made, but since it is similar in name and in number of arguments my IDE says the method is ambiguous. Here's a mock-up of what the two methods look like:

```
methodName(X, Y, Z)
methodName(A, Y, Z)
```

I called on the method, and passed in the value `null` for the first argument for the purpose of my test. Unfortunately I cannot rename the methods, change the order of the arguments or modify the structure of the method in any way. Is there a way I can differentiate between these two methods?

Comment: Find out who designed that API, learn where they live and burn their house down.

Comment: @alexg I seem to remember hitting this before, although I forget which API; it's unlikely to have been new Thread(null, "name") for instance.

Comment: @alexg Since the question said "I'm trying to access a method in a class I made" user1373493 could burn their own house down or redesign the API.

Comment: @alexg overloading is actually quite common and not necessarily a big problem in Java. This sort of issue only arises with `null` which doesn't have a type (and autoboxing in some circumstances).

Comment: @Bruno, it would also arise for every type `T implements X, A`

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/5229890/40342 for an in-depth description of why this issue happens.

Comment: You could consider making a Facade Interface to the library, and call via your Facade instead http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern

Answer (score 89, accepted):

Cast the first argument to the type of the first parameter of the method you want to call, for example:

```
methodName((A) null, y, z);
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you use reflection on the object to acquire the method-list? If so, you could then invoke explicitly the method relevant to you. I do believe fivedigit's answer is probably better though ...