# Overloading method calls with parameter null

Tags: java, overloading

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Method Overloading for NULL parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5229809/method-overloading-for-null-parameter)

In the code below the output is

> String

and if I remove the method with the parameter of type `String` then the output is

> Object

I know how overloading of methods acts when the parameter types don't match exactly but I can not understand how **null** can be treated as an `Object` and/or a `String` parameter.

What is the explanation for this?

```
class C {

    static void m1(Object x) {
        System.out.print("Object");
    }
    static void m1(String x) {
        System.out.print("String");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        m1(null);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It always uses the most specific method according to the [Java specs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/expressions.html#15.12.2.5), section 15.12.2.5.

The intro is reasonably specific about it:

> If more than one member method is both accessible and applicable to a method invocation, it is necessary to choose one to provide the descriptor for the run-time method dispatch. The Java programming language uses the rule that the most specific method is chosen.
>
> The informal intuition is that one method is more specific than another if any invocation handled by the first method could be passed on to the other one without a compile-time type error.

Generally speaking, and at least for code readability, it's always best to try to be as explicit as possible. You could cast your `null` into the type that matches the signature you want to call. But that's definitely a questionable practice. It assumes everyone knows this rule and makes the code more difficult to read.

But it's a good academic question, so I +1 your question.

Comment: But how null match with the signature. It's neither a String nor an Object.

Comment: A String or an Object can be represented as a null, right? Therefore a null can represent either type, therefore both signatures match. But since String extends Object, String is more specific and that method is given preference when the call is ambiguous.

Answer (score 8):

When multiple overloads match a signature, Java picks the most specific method from among them.

The value of `null` matches both `Object` and `String`, but `String` is a subclass of `Object`, so `String` is picked. If you add another overload with a sibling of `String` in the class hierarchy, you'd get a compile error.\

```
// DOES NOT COMPILE
class C {
    static void m1(Object x) {
        System.out.print("Object");
    }
    static void m1(String x) {
        System.out.print("String");
    }
    static void m1(Integer x) {
        System.out.print("Integer");
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        m1(null);
    }
}
```

Here is a [link to a post](http://geekexplains.blogspot.com/2009/06/choosing-most-specific-method-tricky.html) that discusses your code example at some length.

Comment: why `m1(Integer x)` leads to compile-time error?

Answer (score 5):

If you need to force the call of a aprticular overloaded method when passing `null` as parameter, you have to cast it, like this:

```
m1((String)null);
```

By doing this, you make sure you're calling the correct overloaded version of the method.

Answer (score 2):

You have to set the type of `null` to tell Java what function you want to call.

So you do: `m1((Object) null);` to call the implementation with the `Object` parameter and you do `m1((String) null);` to call the other one.

Answer (score 1):

**1.** As **String is also an object** the `JVM` got **confused** to call which method at **runtime**.

**2.** If you want to specify which method to call at runtime, you can do this by **explicit casting**

**eg:**

```
m1((String)null);
```

Comment: That's not the reason JVM got confused. It will always find the most specific method. The reason it gets confused is becaus null is neither a String or an Object.