# Why is this the program's output?

Tags: java, overloading

```
public class OverloadingTest extends Format{

    public int add(String s1){
        System.out.println("With String");
        return 1;
    }
    public int add(Object a){
        System.out.println("With Object");
        return 1;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        OverloadingTest overloadingTest = new OverloadingTest();
        overloadingTest.add(null);
    }

}
```

Why is the output of the program `With String ?`

I have tried reading JLS for 6th Version, but I still could not find the answer.

The only reason I could guess is that the closest match in Inheritance hierarchy is chosen.

So in this case it would take String as Object is its super class.

Comment: You answered your own question :)

Comment: The subber sub class is always chosen....

Comment: @Deepak Bala Oh great. But do you have any reference or documentation which can point this out?

Comment: @Sam - Telthien managed to reference it before me. Take a look at that.

Comment: you can yourself create the reference, just place the public int add(Object a) function before public int add(String s1), and see what output comes this time

Answer (score 3):

This answer is available in the question [*Method Overloading for NULL parameter*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5229809/method-overloading-for-null-parameter):

> Java will always try to use the most specific applicable version of a method that's available (see JLS [§15.12.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2.5)).

So, as a result, `String` is used, because it's the most specific type available. If more than one subtype exists, then you will have to cast `null` to the appropriate type to designate which function you want to run.

Answer (score 1):

This is spelled out in [§15.12.2.5. Choosing the Most Specific Method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2.5):

> If more than one member method is both accessible and applicable to a method invocation, it is necessary to choose one to provide the descriptor for the run-time method dispatch. The Java programming language uses the rule that the most specific method is chosen.
>
> The informal intuition is that one method is more specific than another if any invocation handled by the first method could be passed on to the other one without a compile-time type error.

In your example, `add(Object)` can handle anything that  `add(String)` can. This makes the latter *more specific*. It is therefore the one that gets chosen to handle `null`.

Answer (score 0):

If more than one member method is both accessible and applicable to a method invocation ... The Java programming language uses the rule **that the most specific method is chosen**.

See T[he Java Language Specification](http://books.google.com/books?id=Ww1B9O_yVGsC&lpg=PA349&ots=Se4HcnNchF&dq=java%20%22the%20most%20specific%20method%20is%20chosen%22&pg=PA350#v=onepage&q=java%20%22the%20most%20specific%20method%20is%20chosen%22&f=false)