# How do I test the JavaMailSender of Spring

Tags: java, spring, character-encoding, jakarta-mail

I have a service that has injected the JavaMailSender.
My service configures it and sends a mail.
I'd like to intercept the raw mail to ensure the information is the correct. I'd like to do that in a JUnit.

How would you guys do that?

```
@Service
public class MyServiceImpl {

    @Autowired
    private JavaMailSender _mailSender;

    public void sendMail(String to, String body, String subject){
        ...
        _mailSender.something
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I've done it using [GreenMail](https://greenmail-mail-test.github.io/greenmail/). Take a look at [my blog post about it](https://dimitrisli.wordpress.com/2012/09/17/spring-email-testing-using-greenmail/) where you'll also find a working example.

Comment: Website is down, it would be better if example code were added to the answer.

Answer (score 5):

You can use a test SMTP server, like [Dumbster](https://github.com/kirviq/dumbster). See the example below:

```
@Test
    public void sendSimpleEmailWithCC() {
        // Runs a Dumbster simple SMTP server - default config
        SimpleSmtpServer server = SimpleSmtpServer.start();
        String from = "whoever@from.com";
        String to = "whoever@to.com";
        String messageText = "Good message";
        String title = "Test message";
        String cc = "whoever@cc.com";
        Assert.assertTrue(mailSender
                .sendEmail(from, to, cc, title, messageText));
        server.stop();
        Assert.assertTrue(server.getReceivedEmailSize() == 1);
        Iterator emailIter = server.getReceivedEmail();
        SmtpMessage email = (SmtpMessage) emailIter.next();
        Assert.assertTrue(email.getHeaderValue("From").equals(from));
        Assert.assertTrue(email.getHeaderValue("To").equals(to));
        Assert.assertTrue(email.getHeaderValue("Cc").equals(cc));
        Assert.assertTrue(email.getHeaderValue("Subject")
                .equals("Test message"));
        Assert.assertTrue(email.getBody().equals(messageText));
    }
```

Comment: Do not use dumbster please. It's horribly broken:
 http://sourceforge.net/p/dumbster/bugs/15/. Use greenmail instead.

Comment: The provided link was broken. @TrueDub, can you lease update it?

Answer (score 3):

If your goal is to use just Junit/Mockito and test how MimeMessage was formed before sending then the configuration below should be sufficient:

```
public class EmailServiceTest {

    private EmailServiceImpl emailServiceImpl;

    private JavaMailSender javaMailSender;

    private MimeMessage mimeMessage;

    @Before
    public void before() {
        mimeMessage = new MimeMessage((Session)null);
        javaMailSender = mock(JavaMailSender.class);
        when(javaMailSender.createMimeMessage()).thenReturn(mimeMessage);
        emailServiceImpl = new EmailService(javaMailSender);
    }

    @Test
    public void emailTest() {
        String recipient = "example@example.com"
        EmailRequest request = new EmailRequest();
        request.setRecipient(recipient);
        emailServiceImpl.send(request);
        assertEquals(recipient, mimeMessage.getRecipients(RecipientType.TO)[0].toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: `(Session)null` what is this?

Comment: @DenissM. It was almost a year since you asked which means this information might not relevant to you anymore. When a method is overloaded Java will pick the most specific method (in this case constructor). However, `null` without a type information could be any of the type. This is why you have to cast it to a specific type. https://stackoverflow.com/a/5229890/2231168

Comment: In this case you can also use `Mockito.mock(MimeMessage.class)` instead of `new MimeMessage((Session) null)`. It's a bit more clear.

Comment: About mocking MimeMessage: I tried this, but I got many NPEs, so It is better to use a real MimeMessage. Also it may be better to mock the absolute minimum.

Answer (score 3):

To add a more recent answer to this question and as the linked blog post from 2012 seems to be down occasionally, here's a full example of using GreenMail for writing integration tests with JUnit 5 (assuming you're using Spring Boot's auto-configuration for the `JavaMailSender`).

First, make sure to override the credentials and location of the mail server. You can add an `application.yml` file inside `src/test/resources` for this purpose:

```
spring:
  mail:
    password: springboot
    username: duke
    host: 127.0.0.1
    port: 3025 # default protocol port + 3000 as offset
    protocol: smtp
    test-connection: true
```

Next, Spring Boot's auto-configuration will configure the `JavaMailSender` to connect to GreenMail for your tests. You can use GreenMail's JUnit Jupiter extension to conveniently start/stop a GreenMail server for your tests:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.icegreen</groupId>
  <artifactId>greenmail-junit5</artifactId>
  <version>1.6.1</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

... resulting in the following sample test:

```
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
class JavaMailSenderIT {

  @RegisterExtension
  static GreenMailExtension greenMail = new GreenMailExtension(ServerSetupTest.SMTP)
    .withConfiguration(GreenMailConfiguration.aConfig().withUser("duke", "springboot"))
    .withPerMethodLifecycle(false);

  @Autowired
  private JavaMailSender javaMailSender;

  @Test
  void shouldUseGreenMail() throws Exception {

    SimpleMailMessage mail = new SimpleMailMessage();
    mail.setFrom("admin@spring.io");
    mail.setSubject("A new message for you");
    mail.setText("Hello GreenMail!");
    mail.setTo("test@greenmail.io");


    javaMailSender.send(mail);

    // awaitility
    await().atMost(2, SECONDS).untilAsserted(() -> {
      MimeMessage[] receivedMessages = greenMail.getReceivedMessages();
      assertEquals(1, receivedMessages.length);

      MimeMessage receivedMessage = receivedMessages[0];
      assertEquals("Hello GreenMail!", GreenMailUtil.getBody(receivedMessage));
      assertEquals(1, receivedMessage.getAllRecipients().length);
      assertEquals("test@greenmail.io", receivedMessage.getAllRecipients()[0].toString());
    });
  }
}
```

You can also [use Testcontainers to start a local GreenMail container](https://rieckpil.de/use-greenmail-for-spring-mail-javamailsender-junit-5-integration-tests/) as your local sandbox email server.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding test with GreenMail, you don't want any end to end encryption as it's in your local machine, and for that you need to add this properties to your `application-test.properties` file:

```
spring:
  mail:
    username: xxxx@gmail.com
    password: *********
    host: 127.0.0.1
    port: 3025
    protocol: smtp
    test-connection: false
    properties:
      mail:
        smtp:
          starttls:
            required: false
            enable: false
```

Otherwise you'll get an error: STARTTLS is required but host does not support STARTTLS.

Answer (score 0):

Elaborating on @justinas-jakavonis answer I would suggesto to include this configuration bean in your `src/test/java`

```java
@Configuration
public class JavaMailSenderTestConfiguration {

    private JavaMailSender javaMailSender;

    private MimeMessage mimeMessage;

    @Bean
    JavaMailSender mockMailSender() {
        mimeMessage = Mockito.mock(MimeMessage.class);
        javaMailSender = Mockito.mock(JavaMailSender.class);
        Mockito.when(javaMailSender.createMimeMessage()).thenReturn(mimeMessage);
        return javaMailSender;
    }
}
```