# How null is treated in java at overloading

Tags: java, null

The below code has compilation issue,can some one explain ?How null is treated in this case? All Wrapper class giving the same issue.

```
public class MyTest {  
public static void main(String[] args) {    
    new MyTest().hello(null);
}

public void hello(Object o){
    System.out.println("object");
}

public void hello(Boolean o){
    System.out.println("Boolean");
}

public void hello(Double o){
    System.out.println("Double");
}
}
```

All Wrapper class giving the same issue:

> The method hello(Object) is ambiguous for the type MyTest class.

Comment: Compiler cannot decide `null` denotes `Boolean` or `Double`.

Comment: You should cast that `null` :D

Comment: try to add 'public void hello(String o)' or `public void hello(MyObject o){`. they would be considered as ambiguous methods when you try to invoke the method by passing null

Comment: @PermGenError : yes,u r right.Can u explain this one public void hello(String o){
 System.out.println("String");
}
public void hello(Object o){
 System.out.println("Object");
}
In this case it will take the null as String.If the first case is not working then how the String case is working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`null` isn't really a type on its own so it does now know which overload to pick from.

You could try `(Object) null` and see what happens.

Further to this, null is an applicable value for Object and Double, it might be able to figure it out and compile if you only had a boolean and object (since it wouldn't choose boolean).

Comment: In this case it will take the String method,without casting.So why this happen ?public void hello(String o){
 System.out.println("String");
}
public void hello(Object o){
 System.out.println("Object");
}

Comment: This help a lot http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5229809/method-overloading-for-null-parameter

Comment: Because String extends object, so it calls the extension before the object... it compiles because they are both acceptable nulls