# Calling overloaded functions with "null" reference

Tags: java, overloading

Let us say I have following overloaded functions

```
public class Test {

    public static void funOne(String s){
        System.out.print("String function");
    }

    public static void funOne(Object o){
        System.out.print("Object function");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {            
        funOne(null);
    }
}
```

Why would `funOne(null)` call the method with `String` argument signature? what is the precedence for overloading here?

Comment: Java isn't C++.  You shouldn't really try to compare the two, especially when discussing function overloading.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Agreed , I am guessing it uses class hierarchy to determine the precedence , if I add another funOne(Integer) code does not compile. I am taking out "Is this behavior same in C++?"

Comment: possible duplicate of [Method Overloading for NULL parameter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5229809/method-overloading-for-null-parameter)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The class that is lower in the class hierarchy will have precedence in this case. In other words the more specific class type, which would be `String` in this case because `String` extends `Object` technically.

If you have the following

```
public class A {
    ...
}

public class B extends A {
    ...
}
```

Then when you define overloading methods like the following:

```
public void test(A object) {
    ...
}

public void test(B object) {
    ...
}
```

Then calling `test(null)` will call the second method because `B` is lower in the class hierarchy.

Comment: What would it do if `A` and `B` were cousin types, e.g. both of them extend `Object`?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is more fully answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5229809/method-overloading-for-null-parameter) with references.

Also, you can force a particular method to be called by doing this:

```
    funOne((Object) null);
```

Comment: Thanks , I could make guess but I was searching for [JLS Reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2.5) , thank you for your answer