# Java - Method picking algorithm

Tags: java, methods, compiler-construction

I was messing around with methods and was looking, which Method will be executed if I make two Methods named "hello", with different objects they want and pass a "null" to the method:

```
    public static void main(String... args) {
        hello(null);
    }

    public static void hello(Window w) {
        System.out.println("Hello");
    }

    public static void hello(Frame f) {
        System.out.println("Bye");
    }
```

The output was every time "Bye", but I still don't understand the logic behind that.
After a short research with google, without of any explanation, I decided to ask the question here.

I hope that someone can explain the selection algorithm or give me a link to a explanation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The compiler prefers the most specialized type:

```
public class Parent {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        hello(null); // takes `Child`
    }

    public static void hello(Parent _) {
        System.out.println("SuperClass");
    }

    public static void hello(Child _) {
        System.out.println("SubClass");
    }
}

class Child extends Parent {

}
```

For the reason, take a look at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5229809/method-overloading-for-null-parameter), @Hayden already mentioned in his comment.

Comment: Any reference would be great!

Comment: This stackoverflow link would be helpful in this case - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5229809/method-overloading-for-null-parameter

Answer (score 4):

Java will choose the most specific of the two methods provided (See the [Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/jls7.pdf))

> If more than one member method is both accessible and applicable to a
>   method invocation, it is necessary to choose one to provide the
>   descriptor for the run-time method dispatch. The Java programming
>   language uses the rule that the most specific method is chosen.

As the class hierarchy for [Frame](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Frame.html) is

```
java.lang.Object
    java.awt.Component
        java.awt.Container
            java.awt.Window
                java.awt.Frame
```

An the class hierarchy for [Window](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html) is

```
java.lang.Object
    java.awt.Component
        java.awt.Container
            java.awt.Window
```

Frame is the most specific method, and then, your `public static void hello(Frame f)` will be chosen.