# Why can null be passed to an overloaded Java method?

Tags: java, overloading

I found this Java code from [this site](http://javainterviewhub.blogspot.in/2015/08/core-java-coding-programming-questions.html). I don't understand how it compiles without ambiguous error.

```
 package swain.test;

 public class Test {
     public static void JavaTest(Object obj) {
         System.out.println("Object");
     }

     public static void JavaTest(String arg) {
         System.out.println("String");
     }

     public static void main(String[] args) {
         JavaTest(null);
     }
}
```

Output:

```
String
```

Comment: What wrong with this above code?

Comment: why shouldn't it compile? your answer didn't even ask why it's String and not Object that's printed to the screen so I asume you were just talking about compilation. there is no problem at all

Comment: Probably because `String` IS-A `Object`.

Comment: @SubodhJoshi he calls `JavaTest` with `null` and asks how it does decide to go for the String method

Comment: Related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5229809/method-overloading-for-null-parameter

Comment: @KevinEsche I don't really see that question here

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`null` can be passed to both `JavaTest(String arg)` and `JavaTest(Object obj)`, so the compiler chooses the method with the more specific argument types. Since `String` is more specific than `Object` (`String` being a sub-class of `Object`), `JavaTest(String arg)` is chosen.

If instead of `JavaTest(Object obj)` you had `JavaTest(Integer obj)`, the compilation would have failed, since `Integer` is not more specific than `String` and `String is not more specific than`Integer`, so the compiler wouldn't be able to make a choice.

Comment: But `Integer` also allow `Null` even then it will fail?

Comment: @SubodhJoshi Yes, integer allows null, so the compiler wouldn't be able to choose between `JavaTest(String arg)` and `JavaTest(Integer obj)`.

Comment: Sorry But i don't able to understand what the issue to choose from  `JavaTest(String arg)` and `JavaTest(Integer obj)`..When Compiler can choose between `JavaTest(String arg)` and `JavaTest(Object obj)` We know `Object` can be `Null`,`String` can be `Null` and `Integer` can be `Null` ?

Comment: @SubodhJoshi If two methods have the same names, the same number of arguments and both can accept the parameters you are passing (`null` in this example), the compiler must somehow choose between them. If one method has an argument more specific than the other (as String is more specific than Object), the method with the more specific argument is chosen. Otherwise, the code doesn't pass compilation, since the compiler can't make a choice.

Comment: @SubodhJoshi compiler tries to find best option(Identifying its type) to pass the null as String is more clear type than object because String can have only String value while Object can have String ,Integer etc value So the apropriate type would be String in case of String and Object but incase of String and Integer they both have same priority so the compiler would be confused