# Can we pass test(null) to void display(Object o) //test is an object of the class

Tags: java

Why null goes to method Which Accepts The String

```
class Test {
    public static void test(String s)
    {
        System.out.println("In String");
    }
    public static void test(Object o) {
        System.out.println("In Object");
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        test(null);
    }
}
```

I expect The Result To be 
In Object
as Strings Are Usually Passed in("")

Comment: I guess because `String` is the most specific match?  Try adding another method that takes a `Number` as an argument and see what happens.

Comment: Strings are objects

Answer (score 1):

Java will always try to call the the most specific version of a method. This is part of the Java Language Specification.

Check this answer for more details and a link to the JLS:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/5229890/1426538

Answer (score 0):

See [JLS § 15.12.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2.5).

> If more than one member method is both accessible and applicable to a
>   method invocation, it is necessary to choose one to provide the
>   descriptor for the run-time method dispatch. The Java programming
>   language uses the rule that the most specific method is chosen.
>
> The informal intuition is that one method is more specific than
>   another if any invocation handled by the first method could be passed
>   on to the other one without a compile-time type error.