# Overloading method with parent type and child type argument and passing null while calling. Why method with childtype argument is getting called

Tags: java, overloading

```
 public class Simple{
     public static void main(String args[]){
         method(null);
     }
     public static void method(Object o) {
         System.out.println("Object" + o);
     }
     public static void method(String s) {
         System.out.println("String" + s);
     }
 }
```

Why above code snippet produces "Stringnull" output and not "Objectnull"?

Comment: See answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5229809/method-overloading-for-null-argument

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Method Overloading for null argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5229809/method-overloading-for-null-argument)