# Overloading with void in java

Tags: java, overloading

everyone!
I have two methods which are overloads in the same class.

If I run the below code, I got the error "The method is ambiguous for the type FruitList"

I can't do this:

```
sample.getFruit((Fruit)null);
```

nor this:

```
sample.getFruit((String)null);
```

I cannot change `sample.getFruit(null);`

How can I solve this problem??

```
sample = new FruitList(null);

sample.getFruit(null);------> error
```

```
public class FruitList{

        private Fruit head;
        
        public FruitList(Fruit head){
                this.head = head;
        }
       
        public void getFruit(Fruit object){
        }

        public Fruit getFruit(String name){
        }


}
```

```
public class Fruit{

        private int amount;
        private String name;

        public Fruit(int amount, String name){
               this.amount = amount;
               this.name = name;
        }


}
```

Comment: `sample.getFruit((Game)null)` or `sample.getFruit((String)null)`

Comment: ... or do not call a method `getXZY(...)` if it does not return anything...

Comment: As well as the answers that show you how to convince the compiler to call the method you want, I'd strongly urge you to change the methods. It's very unusual for a method prefixed with `get` not to return something. Usually overloading is used for methods that fundamentally do the same thing, and just express their inputs differently - it looks like that's not going to be the case here.

Comment: For the record, the problem you are experiencing *actually* has nothing to do with the `void` return type.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Method Overloading for null argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5229809/method-overloading-for-null-argument)

Answer (score 2):

You need to help the compiler a bit in this case. Due to `null` being a valid value for both `Game` and `String` you need to instruct the compiler which of the two methods you mean.

So either

```
sample.getFruit((Game) null);
```

Or

```
sample.getFruit((String) null);
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response! Do you have another solution without using (Game) or (String)??

Comment: Only other way I can think of is to use an intermediate variable. `Game game = null; sample.getFruit(game);`

Answer (score 1):

As `Game` and `String` input variable both can be replaced with `null`. Compiler can't decide which method it has to call.

So you can explicitly tell compiler, which method it has to call, by manual type casting to variable as below:

```
sample.getFruit((Game) null);
```

or

```
sample.getFruit((String) null);
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response! Do you have another solution without using (Game) or (String)??